# regex match characters that have to be escaped

Tags: regex, smarty

I have written this regular expression here:

```
\{t\s+i=['|"]([\w\s*]+)['|"]}
```

and it matches anything that is inside the quotes here:

```
{t i="example_match"}
```

now how do I match the string inside the quotes if it is like so?

```
{t i="{$title.$action}"}
```

Comment: `['|"]` doesn't do what you think it does. If you want to match a single or double quote, you want just `['"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working one it seems:

```
\{t\s+i=['"]([\w\s*\{\$\w\.\$\w}]+)['"]}
```

Comment: that would never work. There is no `|` ("or") in character classes. The `|` has no meaning there.

Comment: It would be more like this: `\{t\s+i=['"]([\w\s]*|\{\$\w+\.\$\w+\})\1}`

Comment: Yes, but it would match `{t i=|example_match|}` and I don't think it should. Apart from that, your inner expression (`[\w\s*|\{\$\w\.\$\w}]+`) is wrong in all kinds of ways.